# Php repeated form submit in GET keeps appending same parameters

Tags: javascript, php, forms

This is a very simple form submission issue in GET Method, below is the sample code:

```
<form action="x.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="status">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I submit this form with input value = 1, I get this 
**URL:**

```
 x.php?status=1
```

Again re-submitting the form with input value = 3 I m getting 
**URL:**

```
x.php?status=3&status=1
```

I don't want the parameters to get repeated.
EDIT:

This is what I want on 2nd submit:

x.php?status=3

Comment: it is working right.. no issue found.. may be some issue with your browser

Comment: use header redirect. it will help you to do this kind of tasks... some thing like `header('Location: x.php');`

Comment: post your original code

Comment: The code you provided does not exhibit the behaviour you describe. Check the V in your [MCVE].

Comment: @Rijin Pls check my edit.

This is what I want on 2nd submit:

x.php?status=3

Comment: there is something wrong with your code.. html form don't repeat same parameter.

Comment: make sure you don't have two input field with same name 'status'

Comment: Thanks! @Rijin That solves my issue.

Answer (score -3):

```js
$('input').on('change keyup input', function() {
  $('a').attr('href', 'x.php?status=' + $(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="status">
<a type="submit">Submit</a>
```